# Password function

Tags: c, file

I am very *very new to programming especially using C. I'm trying to create a password function that can read the user name and password from a file and compare it to the username and password entered. The problem is that the code prints the error message even when the password and username I entered is correct.

```
   void Passwrd ()
{
 struct Password pssword[40];
 char username1[20];
 int passw0rd, c;
 bool condition= false;
 printf ("Hello. Please enter the username.\n");
 scanf ("%s", &username1);
 printf ("Hello. Please enter the password\n");
 scanf ("%d",&passw0rd);
 c=0;
 FILE*password;
 password= fopen ("Passwords.txt", "r");
 while (condition== false ){
   while(!feof(password)){
     fscanf (password,"%s  %d \n", &pssword[c].username,&pssword[c].passwrd);
      if ((pssword[c].username==username1) && (pssword[c].passwrd== passw0rd)){
       printf("Thank you! Please continue the program\n");
       feof(password);           
       condition= true;
       }
    else if ((pssword[c].username!=username1) && (pssword[c].passwrd!=passw0rd)){
      printf("Error!!The password or username is invalid\n");
      condition= false;
       c++;
     }
     }
     fclose (password);
  }
 }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question

Comment: Please don't tag languages not related to the question.

Comment: `int passw0rd`: please don't name variables like this.

Comment: `scanf ("%d",&passw0rd);` - why `%d` here? - also having variable names that are nearly the same is a code smell.

Comment: I put the d% there because its reading an integer value.

Comment: I fixed the variable name but it still doesn't work

Comment: Those double astrixes ( ** ) shouldn't be there. Not sure if that's a copy and paste / formatting error or not.

Comment: yeah that was a copy and paste error my bad

Comment: you still didn't write what the problem is and what is your question

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `%d` is correct for `int`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why your code isn't working is that you're comparing strings with `==`. A string is a `char*`, which is just a memory address. When using `==`, you compare the memory addresses. Even if the two strings are the same, they won't be in the same place in memory, so `pssword[c].username` will not `==` `username1`.

To fix this, use the [`strcmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) function, or even better, [`strncmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

---

One other thing to note: you have a logic error. In your `if/else if`, you've handled what happens if:

- both the username and password are correct
- both the username and password are wrong

If one is right and the other is wrong, *neither* condition will be met, so no message will be printed. Just use `else` instead of `else if` in this case, like so:

```
if ((pssword[c].username==username1) && (pssword[c].passwrd== passw0rd)){
   printf("Thank you! Please continue the program\n");
   feof(password);           
   condition= true;
}
else {
  printf("Error!!The password or username is invalid\n");
  condition= false;
   c++;
}
```

Also, you may want to consider renaming your variables a bit. Using a `0` instead of an `o` and misspelling `password` doesn't make it readable. Maybe something like `correct_password`, `correct_user`, `input[c].password`, and `input[c].user` would be easier to follow and debug.